# how to compare between 2 dates without year? only month and day

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, javaquery

I have a function that gets the birthdate( only day and month) and compares if its between 2 dates 
newsigndate is undefined.why? and also AriesFrom and AriesTo.

what to do?

I want to compare the birth date according to day and month for example is 21/3>21/2

yes

return Aries

thanks

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function yourSign() {
  var signDate = $("input[name='birthDate']").val();
  tempsignDate = signDate.split("-").join("/");
  newsignDate = tempsignDate.substring(5, 10);

  var AriesDateFrom = "21/03";
  var AriesDateTo = "20/04";

  var Ad1 = AriesDateFrom.split("/");
  var Ad2 = AriesDateTo.split("/");

  var s = newsignDate.split("/");
  //var date = new Date().getDay() + "/" + new Date().getMonth() + 1 

  var AriesFrom = new Date(Ad1[1], Ad2[2]);


  newsignDate = new Date(s[1], s[2]);

  if (newsignDate == "") {
    alert("enter birthday");

  } else if (newsignDate >= AriesFrom && newsignDate < AriesTo) {
    $("#output").val("Aries");

  }
}

</script>
```

Comment: well, you can't because february has a different number of days in leap years, so you need a year to be accurate ... or, just pick non-leap year and be right most of the time

Answer (score 0):

Here's a tip that might help think about this a little differently:

Instead of thinking about a bunch of date ranges, just think about a list of the last dates of the range. Now you can go through that list and find the first one that is greater than or equal your date. (it will be easier to compare dates is they are in `MMDD` format).

One way to do this in practice is to use the `find()` function of an array to `find` the first date greater than your given date:

```js
// list of signs and last cuttoff
let signs = [ [ 'Capricorn', '0119' ],
[ 'Aquarius', '0218' ],
[ 'Pisces', '0320' ],
[ 'Aries', '0420' ],
[ 'Taurus', '0521' ],
[ 'Gemini', '0621' ],
[ 'Cancer', '0722' ],
[ 'Leo', '0822' ],
[ 'Virgo', '0921' ],
[ 'Libra', '1022' ],
[ 'Scorpio', '1121' ],
[ 'Sagittarius', '1220' ],
[ 'Capricorn', '1231' ] ]


// Jan 1
console.log(signs.find(s => s[1] >= '0101'))
// March 10
console.log(signs.find(s => s[1] >= '0310'))
// Sept 29
console.log(signs.find(s => s[1] >= '0929'))
// Dec 31
console.log(signs.find(s => s[1] >= '1231'))
```

Now you just need to transform your input into `MMDD` format and extract the sign from the array returned by `find()`

Answer (score 0):

in your else if statement variables are replace with these js file code.. i think your requirement is fullfiled,. thank you.

app.js :

```
function yourSign() {

  var signDate = $("input[name='birthDate']").val();
  tempsignDate = signDate.split("-").join("/");
  newsignDate = tempsignDate.substring(5, 10);


  var AriesDateFrom = "03/21";
  var AriesDateTo = "04/20";

  var Ad1 = AriesDateFrom.split("/");
  var Ad2 = AriesDateTo.split("/");
  var s = newsignDate.split("/");

  if(newsignDate == "") {
    alert("enter birthday");

  } 
  else if(s >= Ad1 && s < Ad2) {
    //$("#output").val("Aries");
    alert("Aries");
  }
  else
  {
    alert("not between");
  }}
```

HTML file :

```
<form>
    <input type="date" name="birthDate">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="yourSign();">
</form>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! instead of alert I need that the output will be in the output field.    else if (s >= Ad1 && s < Ad2) {
    output = "Aries";         and then   $("#output").val(output);
  <label for=birthDate>birthdate</label><br /><input type="date" name="birthDate" id="birthDate" /><br />

            <button onclick="yourSign()" id="send">send</button><br />


            <label>yoursign: </label><br />

            <input type="text" name="output" id="output" />

Comment: okay,, replace the input field as a button to button tag                                      <button type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="yourSign();">submit</button>   and than,, the output will be in the output field.    thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you!@bhavesh ajani instead of alert I need that the output will be in the output field.

```
<script>
function yoursign()
 if (s >= Ad1 && s < Ad2) {
output = "Aries";       

$("#output").val(output);

</script>
<body>
```

birthdate

```
        <button onclick="yourSign()" id="send">send</button><br />


        <label>yoursign: </label><br />

        <input type="text" name="output" id="output" />
```